# elementary proof of Dusart's inequality

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

is there any elementary proof for an undergraduate student of this inequality:
${\displaystyle p_{n}<n\ln n+n\ln \ln n\quad {\mbox{for }}n\geq 6}$

Thanks

Comment: That seems stronger than the usual formulation of the PNT so I guess the answer is simply *no*.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I guess this is our D. Burde: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0509095.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, that's me, you know this already:) Think of "there are 913 regular ternary forms". Alexander Schiemann was my phd-Collegue.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I had no idea. That paper is the most influential thing with which I've ever been involved. I put a bunch of related things at   http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/  including Alexander's paper on theta series being different for distinct positive ternaries.